# uipageViewcontroller is showing wrong page

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am using uipageviewcontroller and it is showing wrong index page. I found that there is caching problem in uipageviewcontroller. This bug still persists on ios8. I ve found something in objective - c. Can some one help to translate this code to swift? By the way I don wanna use pageCurl style!

```
__weak YourSelfClass *blocksafeSelf = self; 
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if(finished)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [blocksafeSelf.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:NULL];// bug fix for uipageview controller
            });
        }
    }];
```

Comment: `self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: {finished in if finished {
            
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: {finished in})}
            
            
            }})`